# How do I enter data into the input box of a form using JavaScript in TradingView?

Tags: javascript, forms

how do I put a value in a form using java script. It is a form on the TradinView platform. The input box is identified by a class.
For some reason `document.getElementsByClassName()` does not work.

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("input-uGWFLwEy with-end-slot-uGWFLwEy")[0].value = "3";}
```

The value is displayed in the input box, but the form does not save this input. Any ideas?

link to the page with the form:

https://www.tradingview.com/chart/I3X8Rqto/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhaEn.png)

Comment: Do you use from `document.querySelector(".YOUR_CLASS_NAME")` ?

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so others can reproduce this problem.

Comment: I guess you cannot share the web page of the platform... anyway there's probably an onblur event handled on those input boxes that will take the value typed and will store it somewhere in the application state. Such event gets fired when, after typing inside an input, you click somewhere else on the page. So to simulate user input, after setting the value of element, you should do `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));` ... but that's a speculation.

Comment: link to the page with the form: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/I3X8Rqto/

Comment: I visited that link.. but when opening the chart despite I can see the label `Vol` in the upper-left corner I have no idea how to pop up that modal with the input box you showed in the screenshot. Maybe because the chart is in view only mode and maybe because it depends on the fact you have a paid account there. Anyway I guess you have to try on your own. I gave you a suggestion before that it's quite sure to work.. usually that's how I deal with this kind of scenario. Good luck